# Desktop overloaded with files

Tags: 20.04

I just downloaded a machine learning dataset with about 30GB of image files in a zip file. I intended to extract it to a folder  but I accidentally extracted it to my desktop. My computer only runs on an Intel Pentium so this has pretty much slowed my entire computer to a halt. How can I get rid of these image files?

I've rebooted several times, and I can access applications, although there's about a 5-10 minute delay (not exaggerated) on anything I click. I tried running `rm -rf *.png` but I got a message saying "too many arguments" (which still took me 5 minutes to even see...).  I have figured out that I can still access the terminals tty1-tty5 but I have no clue how to use them, and that I can also try logging in as root, but that there is no password.

As you can see, I'm in a bit of a pickle... any advice?

Comment: Maybe copy files from the desktop you want to keep, and then recursively remove everything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To bypass the limit on command line length, try this in a command prompt:

```
cd <directory with desktop>
printf "%s\0" *.png | xargs -0 rm
```

Explanation:

- `printf "%s\0"` prints its of each following arguments followed by a null separator
- `*.png` is expanded by the shell to a very long list of arguments, but since in bash `printf` is overridden by a shell builtin, the limit on the size of the list doesn't apply.
- So all your .png names are printed to stdout and piped to `xargs-0` (the `-0` tells it to expect null separators) and `xargs` calls `rm` after grouping the input names in arguments lists just long enough to fit in the limits.

If you don't use `bash` there is an equivalent trick with `find ... | xargs rm`.

Comment: I had to do this from the tty terminal but it worked. Thanks!

Comment: Good. Out of curiosity, how many files were there and how long did it take?

Comment: There were around 80,000 images and it deleted all of them in around 5 seconds. Quite impressive, actually.